# Can an AC and a dryer go on the same breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, appliances

I have a sub panel breaker box that has a 30 amp breaker in it right now with a dryer rated at 20.7 amps connected. I want to attach an air condition unit to this sub panel by replacing the current 30 amp breaker with a 60 amp one and just wiring up the ac unit along with the dryer to it. The ac unit is rated at 15.8 amps. Is it ok to have this configuration or do I go with a lower rated breaker? Or do I just forget the idea of having them together on the same breaker?

Comment: There are often three (at least two) different breakers involved: A breaker in the main panel protecting the wire from the subpanel to the main panel, a breaker in the subpanel protecting the subpanel as a whole (this may not be present, and it may actually be larger than the breaker in the main panel), a breaker for each load (dryer, a/c, etc.). Can you post pictures of your main panel and subpanel?

Comment: You can't upsize the breaker like that, but there are still options.  Will the A/C unit be cord-and-plug connected?  What do its instructions say about minimum and maximum breaker size?  Is the dryer currently using a 4-prong (NEMA 14) plug/socket, or the obsolete/dangerous 3-prong NEMA 10?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the subpanel box and of the breaker feeding the subpanel please?

Comment: What size is your sub panel? Are there any open spaces, what is size of the breaker in the main panel feeding the sub what size is the wire feeding the sub from the main panel.  We need all of these questions answered to really help you as manassehkatz asked it is possible your sub panel may have enough ampacity to add your ac unit you mentioned 15.8 amps is the new ac 240v? 110v? Some smaller split systems are 120v and is there an 120v receptacle in the area you plan to place the outside unit? If not you will need to add that also. You may be lucky and have what you need available at the sub

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding the current rating of the wiring, then this question can not be answered safely.  The purpose of the breaker is to limit the current well below the current rating of the wire, so as to prevent overheating (fire) risk.

If the wire is rated to 31 Amperes and a 60A breaker is installed, then it is conceivable (if not inevitable) that a load exceeding 31A will cause overheating (fire).

At the risk of being unkind, I suggest that whatever you do, you consult a qualified professional and not rely on internet advice regarding electrical safety

Comment: Yh I guess I will have to consult an electrician. I'm really trying to figure out a cost to install a unit so that I'm financially prepared. I was happy to know I could get the unit but now just trying to figure out how it's even getting powered and the additional cost is just stressful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot just change out a 30A breaker for a 60A one. The 30A breaker is there to protect the wiring and that is almost certainly wire rated for a 30A max load.  Changing to a 60A breaker is a recipe for disaster (**fire hazard**) and highly illegal.

Additionally, high current loads like a dryer or an HVAC unit must be wired on their own circuit. So your plan fails this requirement also.

Rather than do this, why don't you just run a new circuit for the AC unit and do it right?  That, of course, will involve pulling a permit from your local authority and having it inspected and approved for use.

Comment: While I applaud the question, it indicates that the student requires guidance of a pro to safely design a circuit.

Comment: So if I get the permit from the power company, the planned upgrade should be changing out the sub panel wiring for 60 amp rated wire and putting in a 60 amp breaker. Then I wire a breaker for the AC unit and a breaker for the dryer?

Comment: Permit isn't from the power company, it is from the local Building Department or equivalent - i.e., usually "government".